# PyQGIS get existing ComposerAttributeTable from composition?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-2.14

Working with QGIS `2.14.10x64` in Windows 7 in the QGIS Python Console

I've managed to create a new print composer from a template, and update the layers in the map, and I'd now like to update the associate Composer Attribute Table. But when I use:

```
table = printcomposer['QgsComposition'].getComposerItemById('table')
```

I get a [`QgsComposerFrame`](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsComposerFrame.html) object which doesn't inherit the the [`QgsComposerAttributeTable`](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsComposerAttributeTable.htm) methods and can't seem to find any methods to access contents within the frame. Comparing `table.uuid()` with the uuid in the print composer shows that they are both the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QgsComposerFrame.multiFrame():

```
table_frame = printcomposer['QgsComposition'].getComposerItemById('table')
table = table_frame.multiFrame()
```

Multiframe items like tables and HTML items can have their contents spread over multiple "frames". The getComposerItemById method is returning a frame for a table, but not the table itself. Calling the multiFrame() method returns the frame's parent QgsComposerMultiFrame object, which in this case will be a QgsComposerAttributeTableV2.